# Upload image to folder and image name to database

Tags: php, mysqli

I know this is a long shot to ask but is their anyone that can show me how to upload an image to folder and image name to database? I have looked and everything I find is mysql. Mysql doesn't work for me I get many errors. Here is a code that I have but it will not work for me

```
   <?php
  $hostname_connect= "localhost";
  $username_connect="torcdesi_barron7";
  $password_connect= "Tazmania9292";
  $database_connect="torcdesi_shirt";
   // Create connection
 $connect_solning =  mysqli_connect($hostname_connect, $username_connect, $password_connect, $database_connect) or trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
     mysqli_select_db($connect_solning ,$database_connect) or die (mysqli_error($connect_solning)); 


 if($_POST)
 { 
 // $_FILES["file"]["error"] is HTTP File Upload variables $_FILES["file"] "file" is the name of input field you have in form tag.

 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
 {
 // if there is error in file uploading 
 echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "/>";

 }
 else
 {
  // check if file already exit in "images" folder.
  if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
 {
 echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
 else
  {  //move_uploaded_file function will upload your image.  
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]   ["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
     {
    // If file has uploaded successfully, store its name in data base
   $query_image = "insert into shirt_table (image)    values ('".$_FILES['file']['name']."', 'display','')";
     if(mysqli_query($query_image))
     {
   echo "Stored in: " . "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
   }
   else
    {
   echo 'File name not stored in database';
   }
   }
  }


   }
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid query, you should use:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)
```

You use instead:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)
```

And empty quotes `''` is a value too